# How do I define my route for three parameters using Annotation in my Symfony2 controller?

Tags: symfony, parameters, routes

I've looked at the official Symfony2 Routing documentation, but I'm having trouble understanding it, so I'm asking about how to do it here.

The URI that I wish to use is:

http://my.site.com/app_dev.php/MyWebApp/manageAccount/activate/148/123

This URL is intended to call the manageAccountAction method of the MyWebApp controller with three non-optional parameters, which in this case are:

'activate', 148, and '123'.

The first parameter, 'activate', in this case, may have other specific values, but is always a string and is used to indicate what action the method is to perform.

The middle parameter is a number and is a user id.
The last is an alphanumeric string and is a passcode that must be matched before the action can be performed on the specified user.

Thank you in advance for help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Somethink like that:

```
/**
 * @Route("/MyWebApp/manageAccount/{action}/{userId}/{passcode}", requirements={
 *     "action" = "activate|someaction|otheraction",
 *     "userId" = "\d+",
 *     "passcode" = "[\d\w]+"
 * })
 */
public function manageAccountAction($action, $userId, $passcode)
{
    // ...
}
```

> ...that must be matched before the action can be performed on the specified user.

It seems that you are trying to solve the problem of the business logic in the routing stage and it is not entirely correct. Route usually only defines the *format* of the query but not its *semantics*.

But if you really need that, you can create a [custom `ParamConverter`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter).

Comment: The answer is correct for the question. But I'd suggest that you create several different routes/actions for each {action}. most likely that the logic of activate/delete/edit would be different. It is reasonable to keep it separate in the code instead of having multiple if/else in one action.

Comment: Thank you for the clearly stated suggestion and comment about style.  Yes, it turns out that there are differences in the way that the different actions work, but the logic dealing with the parameters, i.e., validating them and reporting errors concerning them is identical, so at least to me it makes sense to first pass the different actions through a common manager function and then if the parameters are valid to call the now simplified 'action' methods.

Comment: @Stepashka: agree with you.

Comment: @Howard Brown: Also, the Security Component features or the Kernel Events may be helpful if you need a some common process before the controller invocation.